# How do I view full process paths in Activity Monitor?

Tags: activity-monitor, path, macos

I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 and the Activity Monitor.app only shows the name of the process, and I can't configure it to show the full process paths via the GUI settings.

Is it possible to show full process paths in Activity Monitor.app? Maybe with a `default` command to toggle a hidden setting for the app?

Comment: The app doesn’t list it on the main page. Perhaps this is an XY question and you seek to do something different than the answers below?

Comment: @bmike Normally I would just use `sudo htop` for the job, but I wonder if there's a way to do it in the activity monitor... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way: select the process, then View -> Sample Process. In a few seconds a window will pop up like:

[image]

"Path:" contains the fill path to the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the guide on quitting a process and instead of quit, choose the information icon.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/quit-a-process-actmntr1002/mac

When you review the open files and ports, the path to the process is near the top of the list.

[image: Inspect open files and ports in macOS Big Sur Activity Monitor]

You would want to script a better tool for this if you need a general purpose lister and don’t just need an occasional hint where to look for programs.

Comment: It only works for my processes, not the processes of root or other services.